# Google Vision API. FaceDetector NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, computer-vision, google-vision

I'm trying to integrate the Google Vision API for face detection.
But at creation of object FaceDetector, through FaceDetector.Builder the exception works and the application takes off.

The activity in which FaceDetector is created:

```
public class LandmarkActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landmark);
    InputStream inp = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.face);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inp);
    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bmp).build();
    FaceDetector det = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
}}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pobeda.ivan.opencvdetect">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="face" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LandmarkActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

Full Error Log:

```
07-09 15:42:12.073 5284-5284/com.pobeda.ivan.opencvdetect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.pobeda.ivan.opencvdetect, PID: 5284
                                                                        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.vision.face.internal.client.FaceSettingsParcel
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.pobeda.ivan.opencvdetect.LandmarkActivity.onCreate(LandmarkActivity.java:25)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:764)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

p.s: When creating a FaceDetector object in an empty application, there were no errors or exceptions.

Comment: Using different version of google services libraries ??

Comment: Oh, i synchronized the ads services and vision services and everything was up.